# CodeGolf.SE Meta site fails to load with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: support, status-completed, per-site-meta, ssl, code-golf

Here is an example of the problem:

[image: Problem]

I have HTTPS Everywhere installed if that may be doing anything.

Comment: HTTPS Everywhere is interacting poorly with the recent HTTPS changes to cause this. [Our developers and theirs have discussed the issue on their GitHub issue tracker here.](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until HTTPS Everywhere is updated (looks like [Nick's changes](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/pull/9110) were merged in, so hopefully soon), the only thing to do is either avoid child metas or disable the addon. (I don't use it myself, so not sure if it's possible to set up an exclusion for meta.*.stackexchange.com.)

Answer (score 5):

HTTPS Everywhere merged my fix for this in about a month ago, so no one should be seeing this anymore. If you are: stop blocking plugin updates!

Comment: Not occurring anymore